# Android - get ActivityRecognition service values back to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, intentservice, activity-recognition

I’m working with the `ActivityRecognitionClient` class to get the data of the User’s activity whether he walks, runs or on bicycle etc…

The thing is that working with `PendingIntent`, so I’m able to start the `PendingIntent`, and in the function `onHandleIntent` I even can extract logs of the values of the user’s activity.

The Problem is that I can't extract the values to the `MainActivity`.

Although I saw a solution [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/ActivityRecognition).

He uses `SharedPreferences` to pass the data, and in the `MainActivity` he implements [SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html). so whenever the `SharedPreference` is edited in the `IntentService` **or in any other class**, the `MainActivity` gets a callback.

I don't think that this is the best solution but I didn't found any other solution.

But what I don't understand is why there is no any callback to the `PendingIntent.getService()` function apart from `OnSuccessListener` and `OnFailureListener`.

What I've done until now is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/asafbaibekov/66de024050524a4e943c65fff93c517c)

Thanks for helpers!

Answer (score 1):

To get data from a service to the activity you can use Intents, local broadcast receiver, or you can bind your activity to your service. If you bind to your service you can for example simply register a callback but do take care that you do not update your views from the services background thread (eg use a handler to communicate from a background thread to the UI thread)

Comment: TL;DR - Bind the service